# How to do CAS authentication in the background (Using normal login screen) (Jasperserver)

Tags: cas, jasperserver

currently if you got to the jasperserver page (nwc.ac.ba:8085/jasperserver-pro) it directs you to the CAS login (nwc.ac.ba:8443/cas-server-webapp-3.5.0/login...)
and then after the user logs in the user is directed back to the jasperserver home page

My Question is how can I keep the jasperserver login page and if the user logs the cas login will happen in the background (a.k.a username & password is sent to cas server, and then cas directs back to jasperserver)

Comment: I don't know anything about CAS authentication, so forgive me if you've already exhausted all of the options in this documentation, but here's a link to the CAS authentication section of the JasperReports Server Authentication Cookbook: http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-authentication-cookbook/cas-authentication